# How do I use MAMP, SVN Server, and the SVN client all on the same machine?

Tags: macos, svn, localhost, mamp

I have a dev box (mac mini) that hosts all of my development sites. I have SVN server configured on the server and have created 2 repositories so that I can push my work from my laptop to the server. Now I want to "update" the webdev directory (where I have my files set up for MAMP) so that I can see my changes on my dev server. Is there any way to do this? I've tried connecting to localhost using the SVN client and I get a 200 OK error -- and another error I can't remember how to recreate.

Can SVN Server, Client, and Webserver all co-exist on the same machine -- and if so -- how do I update/commit/checkout using the client on the same machine?

Comment: `200 OK` shouldn't be an error? But you can always just use `file://` as the repository URL if it's on the same disk.

Comment: I tried that as well (looking at a few forums to try to import an existing directory to the server and wasn't able to connect using file:// or file:///.

Comment: "I can push my work from my laptop to the server." which URL of repository do you use?

Answer (score 0):

> Can SVN Server, Client, and Webserver all co-exist on the same machine

Yes

> how do I update/commit/checkout using the client on the same machine

same way as for any remote host - connect to repo and use svn commands

BTW - site as working copy is "worst practice"

Comment: I have this set up as my bookmark to try to connect while I am connected via remote desktop to my server and it won't let me connect.
http://myusername@localhost:9880/Users/myuserfold/Public/webdev/www.mydevsite.com

What's wrong with using this a dev server? Please forgive my ignorance...I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hang on - are you using the apache module to host as http or svnserve (the svn:// protocol)? Either way you shouldn't need to give it the full path to the repository unless you've started the server at the root of your filesystem (!). What's the root path the server is hosting from?